# Vue - Child selection triggers parent method

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to call a parent method when a dropdown item changes. The concept would kind of look like this:

Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <child ref="someRef">
</template>
...
methods: {
  doSomething() {
    // use someRef.selectedItems and variables in the parent.vue class to perform logic
  },
}
```

Child.vue

```
<template>
  <v-select v-model="selectedItems" @change="doSomething" />
<template>
```

How do I correctly wire it together so that a dropdown selection in the child triggers a parent method?  Is this a clear case for emit / vuex / or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with emit here. (At least I would not add Vuex just for the purpose of this problem, although I generally use it in pretty much every app.)

In your child component's `doSomething` handler emit an event with the selected value:

`this.$emit('selected', value)`

In you parent component, hook up a listener to the child's event:

`<child @selected="onSelected">`

Add `onSelected(value)` to your methods. It will be called whenever the event is emitted from the child component.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason this always seems to be 1 behind when I console.log the selected contents from inside onSelected

Comment: Would vuex be a smarter choice if I have n number of child.vue files within the parent? In other words, I perform a filter in the parent based off multiple dropdowns? Or would emit still be the way to go?

Comment: FYI using '@input' works as expected whereas using @change' seems to be 1 behind

Comment: @ekjcfn3902039 concerning the use of Vuex: that's really a matter of taste. I still would argue against it for this specific purpose: Using a store to distribute child values means that you strongly couple that component to its place in the app. That's problematic if the component should be reused in another context. Also, testing a "pure" component (without side effects, like changing the store) is way simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!